# How to handle an null object from the database in React use state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I have a chicken and egg problem. I have a JSON object in my database which I use in my state like:

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState(myObject);
```

Were `myObject` is a JSON Object that's coming from my database.

**Problem**

The issue I have is that for me to have the object in my database, I have to add it from the client, which I can't do because I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
```

Because yes it's true, there isn't an object yet. So I can't update my database from my form on the page since the page won't load because the is no JSON in the DB. (What comes first, chicken and egg situation)

I tried to use useEffect to create set a value in myObject trying to seed the DB so that it wont be empty:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setMyObject([{name: 'Alice',salary: 100,}]);
    }, []);
```

But this isn't working.

I tried to set the state conditionally like this.

```
if (myObject === null) {
       const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState(myObject);
    } else {
        const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([{name: 'Alice',salary: '100'}]);
    }
```

But this isn't allowed.

How do I approach this problem?

**Requested code**

When I get my Object from DB, i save it to the state myObject. I update the DB with this.

```
updateData = async () => {
        try {
            await fetch(`/api/posts/${id}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    Object: myObject,
            })
        })
        refreshData()
    } catch (error) {
        toast.error('Document could not be updated')
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: can you add the code that fetches the object from DB ?

Comment: thnx, i was more curious about `refreshData` but i'm wondering if doing `const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState( myObject || [{name: 'Alice',salary: '100'}]);` would solve your problem

Comment: Let me try this. refreshData is just a function that reloads data instead of refreshing the page

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for that, it worked! please could you answer the question and I'll accept it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
```

because you're trying to map over a `null`. What you can do to avoid this is to initialize your `formFields` state as an array, like so:

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([]);
```